# Is it possible to put my own custom control or composite inside listviewer of Jface

Tags: eclipse, swt, jface

I wanted to display list of custom controls or composite in a list .I was thinking to use listview But I stumbled that listview only supports text or image it does not support to put composite inside (Even I see its same with atble viewer too .Is there any way this can be done

Comment: This isn't easy. Using `OwnerDrawLabelProvider` with `TableViewer` gives you complete control of drawing the cells in the table.

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish that, with some extra effort, have a look to this:Snippet

https://github.com/eclipse/eclipse.platform.ui/blob/master/examples/org.eclipse.jface.snippets/Eclipse%20JFace%20Snippets/org/eclipse/jface/snippets/viewers/Snippet010OwnerDraw.java

in the "**CountryEntries** classes" you can find different methods that draw the parts:

```
drawFlag
drawName
drawCupYear
```